# How come a number inputted by a user isn't recognized if I try to find it's index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

num = input('Enter a number: ')
a.append(int(num))
a.sort()
print(a)
print(a.index(num))
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 78
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 78, 89]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\linda keator\PycharmProjects\game_1\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(a.index(num))
ValueError: '78' is not in list
```

I made a python program that requests input from the user, which adds to the list of numbers above (fibonacci sequence for no reason).

How do I program it so that it will return the index of the number added from the input? It's sorted smallest to biggest with `.sort()`. It says that 78 isn't in the list, even though it's being displayed as part of list just above the error message. What's the issue in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to find the index of `num` which is a `str` object because it was the return value of the `input()` function which always returns a `str`. You correctly cast `num` to `int` when you appended to `a`, but this isn't a permanent modification. Before anything you need to do

```py
num = int(num)
```

Then you can add it to your `list` of numbers. A safer approach to this would be to get user input via a `while` loop:

```py
def get_integer_input():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input, try again!\n")
    return num
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I guess I figured the one integer cast was permanent. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome, and nope! Strings are immutable objects. Any function on an immutable object will always return a new object. This includes casting, as casting is simply a function which attempts to cast the input object to a new object of the requested type. They are "pure" functions in that they do not modify their input at all. PS - if you're satisfied with my answer, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: @goatpasta The error also hints at the problem, because it says `'78'` (with quotes, a string), rather than just `78` (without quotes, an int).

Answer (score 0):

The last line of code you have it looking for a str, not an integer:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

num = input('Enter a number: ')
a.append(int(num))
a.sort()
print(a)
print(a.index(int(num)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding 'str' to a list. Try it like this:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]

num = input("Enter Number:")

#a.append(int(num)) here you are appending str

print(type(num)) 
#Output <class 'str'>

b = int(num)
a.append(b)
a.sort()
print(a)
print(a.index(b))
```